# Why doesn't three.js work for me in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, three.js

I am using the [three.js](https://threejs.org) library with Notepad+ and Chrome but I would like to use it in [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/).

I have tried to import it by adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>` but NetBeans does not recognize the constructor.

For example:
`new THREE....();`

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to look more like a question and make it easier for people to quickly understand what you're asking.

I also rephrased some of your sentences to make them easier to read and added links to some of the tools you mentioned.

Finally, I marked some of your code examples as code (using `).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working (three lib is loaded correctly), then it's just netbeans warning you that it don't recognize the THREE namespace. You can ignore this warning by writing:

```
/* global THREE * /
```

at the top of your file.